# how can I call a screen with a button action (xcode)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am developing a Window Based app for iPhone. I use Interface Builder to build Interface.  I want to call a new screen with a Button Action. How can I call the screen with Button action ?

Comment: I don't understand why his question was down-voted. I wish people would explain why they down-vote when they do so. Feedback is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

By pushing the new controller onto the top of the stack of windows. For example:

```
EnterNameController *newEnterNameController = [[EnterNameController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EnterName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:newEnterNameController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Its working at Navigation based application. But Its not working at Window based application.

Comment: As far as I know, you should always use a navigation controller even when you think you are opening screens (or windows) in a non-hierarchical way.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has an extraordinary amount of sample code, and this question (as well as many others) could easily be solved by simply visiting Apple's iPhone dev site.
[iPhone Dev Site](http://developer.apple.com/iphone)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a navigation controller, push it onto the navigation controller's stack, as alamodey suggested.

If you want it to be a modal controller (that is, slide up from the bottom and cover the previous controller's view, like the Bookmarks screen in Safari), present it as a modal view controller:

```
[self presentModalViewController:myNewController animated:YES];
```

When you want to bring the old controller back, dismiss the modal view controller.  From inside the modal view controller:

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If you don't want to do either, just remove the current controller's view from the window and add the new controller's:

```
UIView * containingView = self.view.superview;
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[containingView addSubview:myNewController.view];
```

If you go this route, you may want to look into +[UIView beginAnimations:context:], +[UIView setAnimationTransition:onView:], and +[UIView commitAnimations] (if I recall the method names correctly--check the documentation) to animate the transition.  You should almost always animate any switch between screens in iPhone OS.

Answer (score 1):

(work in .m class)

```
#import "classtocall.h"
- (IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender 
{
classtocall *mvc = [[classtocall alloc]initWithNibName:@"classtocall" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:mvc animated:NO];
}
```

(for window based application)
define in .h class

```
- (IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender;
```

where "classtocall" is the class you want to call.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to download sample applications from XCode help. Try Elements and UIcatalog.  There are also other - type 'pushViewController' or 'addSubview' adn 'makeKeyAndVisible' in help and download samples

Answer (score 0):

```
nextscreenViewController *login = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nextscreenidentifier"];

nextscreenidentifier.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[self presentModalViewController: nextscreenidentifier animated: YES];
```